# Fubini Study metric on the complex projective space $\mathbb{PC}^m$

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, holomorphic-bundles

I study Andrei Moroianu's [Lectures on Kähler Geometry](https://moroianu.perso.math.cnrs.fr/tex/kg.pdf)
and have some troubles to understand the proof of Lemma 7.1.
The claim is that the tensor $h$ that gives some called
Fubini–Study metric on the complex projective space is
positive definite:

[image]

All we have to do to show that $h$ is positive definite is to prove
is that the restriction of $h$ to some local holomorphic chart
$\phi: U_j \to \mathbb{C}^m$ defined by $\hat{h}(X,Y) := 
i \partial \overline{\partial} u(X, JY)$,
for all $X,Y \in T\mathbb{C}^m$ is positive definite:

The auxilary function $u: \mathbb{C}^m \to \mathbb{R}$  is defined by
$u(z)= \log(1+ \vert z \vert^2)$. The caluculation at point $p=(r,0,...,0) \in \mathbb{C}^m$ in the proof shows

$$\tag{1}  \partial \overline{\partial} \log(1+ \vert z \vert^2)= \frac{1}{(1+r^2)^2}(dz_1 \wedge d \overline{z_1} +
(1+r^2) \cdot \sum_{i=2}^m dz_i \wedge d \overline{z_i})  $$

Here the $dz_i$ are generators of the dual space of
$T^{1,0}\mathbb{C}^m$ and $d\overline{z_i}$ are generators
of the dual space of
$T^{0,1}\mathbb{C}^m$
where these spaces are eigenspaces of $i$ and $-i$ with respect the
endomorphism $J$ on the compexified tangent bundle

$$(T\mathbb{C}^m)^{\mathbb{C}}=
T\mathbb{C}^m \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} \mathbb{C}=
T^{1,0}\mathbb{C}^m \oplus T^{0,1}\mathbb{C}^m$$

See 1.4 The complexified tangent bundle page 9. Obsverve that since
$\mathbb{C}^m$ is already complex the endomorphism
$J$ on $(T\mathbb{C}^m)^{\mathbb{C}}$ is simply the multiplication by
imaginary $i$.

***Question:*** Why if we choose some $X,Y \in T\mathbb{C}^m$ then

$$\tag{2} \hat{h}(X,Y)= \frac{2}{(1+r^2)^2}  Re(X_1\overline{Y_1} +(1+r^2) \cdot 
\sum_{i=2}^m X_i \wedge d \overline{Y_i})$$

That is we have to insert $X$ and $JY$ in

$$\tag{3} \hat{h}= i \partial \overline{\partial} \log(1+ \vert z \vert^2) =
\frac{i}{(1+r^2)^2}(dz_1 \wedge d \overline{z_1} +
(1+r^2) \cdot \sum_{i=2}^m dz_i \wedge d \overline{z_i})$$

which we have calculated in $(1)$. I not understand why the result of this evaluation is (2) as stated
in last line of the Lemma's proof. Where the $2$
and the $Re$ come from? Why it's well defined? The summands
$dz_i \wedge d \overline{z_i}$ acts
on $T^{1,0}\mathbb{C}^m \times T^{0,1}\mathbb{C}^m$, but
$X, JY$ live in $T\mathbb{C}^m$.

The claim is that the action of  $i \cdot dz_j \wedge d \overline{z_j}$
on the pair $(X, JY)$ is $Re(X_j \overline{Y_j})$. Clearly it
'sees' only the $j$-th components but the rest of what happens there
is obscure to me.

Thinking simpler assume $m=1$. Then $X, JY \in T\mathbb{C}$.
Why $i \cdot dz \wedge d \overline{z}(X, JY)= 2 \cdot Re(X \overline{Y})$?

Answer (score 2):

Moroianu seems to be using the convention that $dz_i\wedge d\bar{z_i} = dz_i\otimes d\bar{z_i} - d\bar{z_i}\otimes dz_i$. With this in mind, we have

\begin{align*}
(dz_i\wedge d\bar{z_i})(X, Y) &= (dz_i\otimes d\bar{z_i})(X, Y) - (d\bar{z_i}\otimes dz_i)(X, Y)\\
&= dz_i(X)d\bar{z_i}(Y) - d\bar{z_i}(X)dz_i(Y)\\
&= X_i\overline{Y_i} - \overline{X_i}Y_i\\
&= X_i\overline{Y_i} - \overline{X\overline{Y_i}}\\
&= 2\operatorname{Re}(X_i\overline{Y_i}).
\end{align*}

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Two aspects I not completely understand: assume as in my last sentence that $m=1$ that is $dz \in (T^{1,0}\mathbb{C})^*, d\overline{z} \in (T^{0,1}\mathbb{C})^*, X, Y \in T\mathbb{C}$. How to interpret the expresions $dz(X)$ and $d\overline{z}(X)$? Do we implicitly identify $T\mathbb{C}$ with $T^{1,0}\mathbb{C}$ and $T^{0,1}\mathbb{C}$ here? How there isomorphisms are explicitely given?

Comment: and second remark: The computation starts with $\hat{h}(X,JY)$. I assume then we used here also $d\overline{z}(JY)= d\overline{z}(i \cdot Y)=-i \cdot d\overline{z}(Y)$ implicitely?

Comment: There is a natural inclusion $T\mathbb{CP}^m \hookrightarrow T\mathbb{CP}^m\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C} \cong T^{1,0}\mathbb{CP}^n\oplus T^{0,1}\mathbb{CP}^n$, so $dz_i(X)$ is just $dz$ of the $(1,0)$-part of the image of $X$. It is true that $dz(JY) = idz(Y)$ and $d\bar{z}(JY) = -id\bar{z}(Y)$, but I wouldn't say that's implicit, it follows from all the definitions. If you're struggling with this aspect of complex geometry (which I still do), section 1.2 of Huybrechts' *Complex Geometry - An Introduction* is a good resource. I'm sure earlier sections of Moroianu's book are also helpful.